# get array key name passed into the function like $array['key']

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the array key name this way?

```
$array = ("first" => 1);

function f($object)
{
echo(???); //should give first
}

f($array['first']);
```

Comment: what do you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible if you pass only the value into the function like `f($object['first'])`, the key name has no relation to the passed value in that case.

You need to pass the entire array (`f($array)`) and use:

```
echo key($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want to get, but I guess this will help you:

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'foobar');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

This will return

```
foo = bar
baz = foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
$array = ("first" => 1);

function f($object, $key) {
    echo($key); // will give first
    echo($object[$key]); // will give 1
}

f($array, 'first');
```